# Can I have a specific step run in a SQL Agent job?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I have a multi-step SQL Agent job with steps 1-20. Is it possible to run one step only or is the only option to start the job at a particular step (and then watch as it runs through all subsequent steps)?

I've looked at the documentation for [sp_start_job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx) and have tried going through the GUI of SMSS, but can't figure out if it's possible to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Sure if you right click on the SQL Server Job and Start at Step. That will start at a certain point and then do the remaining steps after.

`Open SQLServerManagementStudio` --> `SQL Server Agent Job` --> `Select the job` --> `Right Click` --> `Start Job At Step` --> `Highlight the job and click START.`

Update:
If you needed to do one step only couldnt you set the success to : `Quit the job as Success`

Comment: The question is *is it possible to run one step only*.

Comment: @sasfrog  not according to this: and then watch as it runs through all subsequent steps